How can I scale my whole page with the size of the window?
This is the code that I am using to learn:
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()


all = tk.Label(root)
welcome = tk.Label(all, text="Welcome", font=("Verdana", 50), anchor="center")
welcome.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
welcome2 = tk.Label(all, text="To my software", font=("Verdana", 30), anchor="center")
welcome2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
start = tk.Button(all, text="Start", width=15, height=1, font=("Verdana", 12))
start.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
all.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)


root.mainloop()

How can I make the size of this all scale up and down dependent on the size of the tkinter window?
This differs from TkInter Label Change Font Size by Text Length because I would like to also scale the Button and the Entry boxes that are also in the parent "all" label. Sort of like zooming in and out of it all.

This question is similar to: TkInter Label Change Font Size by Text Length. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Don't use Python reserve all. Use another variable.

@toyotaSupra what would root.geometry('400x400') do for me here?

In tkinter, you can easily change the window size based on its contents (by using .grid or .pack). To scale the contents based on the window size, you will have to bind to "<Configure>" (an event fired when the window size is changed) and configure each widget separately by changing its font. Changing the font is the only way to scale the UI in tkinter.

@TheLizzard So what you're saying is that there's really no way to scale everything (Buttons, Text, and Entry boxes) to be independent from monitor resolution. I would like to make it look the same regardless of the resolution of the monitor (In Fullscreen mode).

Basically yes but you can always get the screen resolution and scale the font by that amount. The only thing determining the size of Text, Button, Entry is the padding and font size.

A label is not designed to hold other widgets although it can be.  Normally a frame is used instead.

From what I have found, the easiest way to do this would be to make it look good on one resolution and then have a function scale the font relative to the resolution. Like this:
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

def new_size(size):
    change = root.winfo_screenwidth()/ 1920
    print(change)
    return int(size * change)


main = tk.Frame(root)
welcome = tk.Label(main, text="Welcome", font=("Verdana", new_size(50)), anchor="center")
welcome.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
welcome2 = tk.Label(main, text="To my software", font=("Verdana", new_size(30)), anchor="center")
welcome2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
start = tk.Button(main, text="Start", width=15, height=1, font=("Verdana", new_size(12)))
start.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
main.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.mainloop()


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
